# force:createRecord defaultFieldValues not working with dependant picklist

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dependent-picklist, create-records

I'm working with force:createRecord trying to pre-populete some field values and everything is working fine except for the dependent picklist I'm filling.

```
                let createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
                params = {
                    "entityApiName": 'Case',
                    "recordTypeId": selectedRecType,
                    "defaultFieldValues": {
                        "Category__c" : "Customers", //controlling field
                        "Subcategory__c" : "Asignation", //dependant field
                    }
                };
                createRecordEvent.setParams(params);
                createRecordEvent.fire();
```

But this is what I got:

[image]

I've checked that this was a known issue back in 2020 but is there now a workaround to accomplish this? Or is still not working?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ability to [set default values for dependent picklist values](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_default_value_dependent_picklist.htm&type=5&release=232) was not brought to Cases, which is why it's not working for you.

> You can now prepopulate a record event with default values in
> dependent picklists. **Default values on dependent picklists are
> available on accounts, opportunities, contacts, leads, and custom
> objects.**

It's not expected to work, currently, for Cases. You'll have to look at using  a different mechanism for this if setting a default value is a blocker. A Flow screen could handle setting the default values, but that assumes there's not a large amount of fields on the page layout that you'd have to re-create.